# How to get price to update when changing attrubutes within a View

Tags: views, commerce

I have a view and have a relationship so I can display the product price. When I change an attribute option, the price field doesnt dynamically change.

I think I will have to do something with the style settings and change to DIV, check create a CSS class and add a tokenized CSS class so it will change when the product id changes? but i cant get it to work.

What I've done so far:

1. Add relationship Content: Referenced products
2. I have 3 fields: 1.
   content nid (excluded from display) 2. product add to cart form. 3.
   commerce product price field.

**At this point i can display the price but it doesnt update when i select various attribute options**

3. Style Settings, Customize field HTML --> DIV --> Create a CSS class

I think under the create a CSS class i need to print a CSS class with a product id token or something like that, but cant find the correct token or CSS valule.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

1. you must add a content: NID field and exclude from display to get the token of [nid] available
2. Then under style settings of the price field, select 'customize field HTML'
3. HTML element = DIV
4. Select Create a CSS class
5. the CSS class for Price is: node-[nid]-product-commerce-price

The NID token will update when a certain attribute changes. This can also be applied to other fields as well finding the CSS with firebug and then adding in the [nid] token